# Incremental background position animation with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, background-position

I've got a 100% wide and 284px high div called #photoStripe with a 5000px wide background image. Then left and right nav buttons over it. The idea is to be able to pan left an right, by animating the background image incrementally left and right.

I'm using the [popular background position plugin](http://www.protofunc.com/scripts/jquery/backgroundPosition/), which allows you to animate the x and y values of the background position simultaneously.

Well, the background animates, but it only does once. (Can't click again and again).Any ideas?

jQuery:

```
$('#photoStripe').css({backgroundPosition:"0 0"});

$('a.moveLeft').click(function(){
    $('#photoStripe').stop().animate({backgroundPosition:'-=200px 0'}, {duration:500});
});
$('a.moveRight').click(function(){
    $('#photoStripe').stop().animate({backgroundPosition:'+=200px 0'}, {duration:500});
});
```

CSS:

```
#photoStripe {
width:100%;
height:286px;
text-align:center;
overflow:hidden;
background:url(../_images/photo_stripe.jpg);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems fine in FF when I'm checking this code, here's my code, are you sure you have everything there? Could you post your whole code pls

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style type="text/css">
#photoStripe {
width:100%;
height:286px;
text-align:center;
overflow:hidden;
background:url(wallpaper.jpg);
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

$('#photoStripe').css({backgroundPosition:"0 0"});

$('a.moveLeft').click(function(){
    $('#photoStripe').stop().animate({backgroundPosition:'-=200px 0'}, {duration:500});
});
$('a.moveRight').click(function(){
    $('#photoStripe').stop().animate({backgroundPosition:'+=200px 0'}, {duration:500});
});

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" class="moveLeft">moveLeft</a>
<a href="#" class="moveRight">moveRight</a>
<div id="photoStripe">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Let me know, I'll try to help :)

Cheers

G.

Comment: Thank you Gregory!! I took your code and incrementally added what other code I had on my page and found the problem. It was because I was calling the background position plugin. Apparently it doesn't do incremental animations, and is more suited to rollover effects, and anything where you are animating the x and y position simultaneously.